# Why doesn't @NotNull raise a compile time error?

Tags: java, android, annotations

I just came across annotations , and I started using them. I made an interface which had a method signature with a @NotNull param like

```
 interface {
    public void test(@NotNull CustomObject c );
}
```

I implemented the method in a class

```
clazz implements interface
{
@Override
public void test(@NotNull CustomObject c)
{
}
}
```

I expected `new Clazz().test(null)` to complain while i compiled , but it is not . I am using Android studio , which is built on Intellij .

If these annotations are not supposed to give us compile time errors , then what are they used for ?

Comment: Yes you are right, `@NotNull` is not used to get compile time errors in Java by default. 

For IntelliJ you may configure, that the IDE outputs warnings each time the `@NotNull` contract is violated inside your code (for more details take a look at Jetbrains [docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/nullable-and-notnull-annotations.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using it for the wrong porpouse.

> @NotNull
>
> The @NotNull Annotation is, actually, an explicit contract declaring the following:
>
> A method should not return null.
> A variable (like fields, local variables, and parameters) cannot hold null value.
> For more information and code examples, refer to online how-to.
>
> IntelliJ IDEA warns you if these contracts are violated.

Please check the resource link for more info https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/nullable-and-notnull-annotations.html